# Python: regex matching anything inside parentheses (also other parentheses)

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with python and regex and I'm trying to transform a string like the following:

```
(1694439,805577453641105408,'\"@Bessemerband not reverse gear  simply pointing out that I didn\'t say what you claim I said. I will absolutely riot if (Brexit) is blocked.\"',2887640,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1649240,805577446758158336,'\"Ugh FFS the people you use to look up to fail to use critical thinking. Smh. He did the same thing with brexit :( \"',2911510,NULL,NULL,NULL),
```

Into a list like the following:

```
[
    [1694439, 805577453641105408, '\"@Bessemerband not reverse gear  simply pointing out that I didn\'t say what you claim I said. I will absolutely riot if (Brexit) is blocked.\"', 2887640, NULL, NULL, NULL],
    [1649240, 805577446758158336, '\"Ugh FFS the people you use to look up to fail to use critical thinking. Smh. He did the same thing with brexit :(\"', 2911510, NULL, NULL, NULL]
]
```

The main problem here is that, as you can see, there are parentheses also inside the text that I don't want to split.
I've already tried things like `\([^)]+\)`, but obviously this splits at the first `)` it finds.

Any clues how to solve this?

Comment: That's not what regexes are designed for. Although there are extensions that allow balancing brackets, without these extensions, the *pumping lemma* specifies a regex cannot do that.

Comment: Regular expression cannot count hence they cannot extract text with matched quotes and parentheses. You need a parser. See PLY, PyParsing, Lark, etc.

Comment: Although as stated by @WillemVanOnsem regex is not designed for doing this, if you know the first column is always a bunch of numbers yo could use it as a anchor point. See [regex Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: I don't understand why everyone's saying regex isn't the right tool for this. Regex matches patterns, and there is very much a pattern in this input and output. As long as all single quotes `'` in those strings are properly escaped, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Rawing Any suggestion how to solve it then?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you're looking for?

```
big = """(1694439,805577453641105408,'\"@Bessemerband not reverse gear  simply pointing out that I didn\'t say what you claim I said. I will absolutely riot if (Brexit) is blocked.\"',2887640,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1649240,805577446758158336,'\"Ugh FFS the people you use to look up to fail to use critical thinking. Smh. He did the same thing with brexit :( \"',2911510,NULL,NULL,NULL),"""
small = big.split('),')
print(small)
```

What I'm doing is splitting on `),` Then just loop through and split on commas like normal. I'll show a basic approach that can certainly be optimized:

```
new_list = []

for x in small:
    new_list.append(x.split(','))
print(new_list)
```

Now the downside to this is that there's an empty list, but you could drop it later.

Comment: The only problem with your solution is that there might ba a case in which the string inside the parentheses has "),".. Anyway I've found a website that does exactly what I needed http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward regex solution that captures each comma-separated value in a different group:

```
\(([^,]*),([^,]*),'((?:\\.|[^'])*)',([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^)]*)
```

Usage:

```
input_string = r"""(1694439,805577453641105408,'\"@Bessemerband not reverse gear  simply pointing out that I didn\'t say what you claim I said. I will absolutely riot if (Brexit) is blocked.\"',2887640,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1649240,805577446758158336,'\"Ugh FFS the people you use to look up to fail to use critical thinking. Smh. He did the same thing with brexit :( \"',2911510,NULL,NULL,NULL),"""

import re
result = re.findall(r"\(([^,]*),([^,]*),'((?:\\.|[^'])*)',([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^)]*)", input_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested parenthesis are not a problem here since they are enclosed between quotes. All you have to do is to match quoted parts separately:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"[^()',]+|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|(\()|(\))", re.DOTALL)

s = r'''(1694439,805577453641105408,'\"@Bessemerband not reverse gear  simply pointing out that I didn\'t say what you claim I said. I will absolutely riot if (Brexit) is blocked.\"',2887640,NULL,NULL,NULL),(1649240,805577446758158336,'\"Ugh FFS the people you use to look up to fail to use critical thinking. Smh. He did the same thing with brexit :( \"',2911510,NULL,NULL,NULL),'''

result = []

for m in pat.finditer(s):
    if m.group(1):
        tmplst = []
    elif m.group(2):
        result.append(tmplst)        
    else:
        tmplst.append(m.group(0))

print(result)
```

If your string can also contain parenthesis not enclosed between quotes, you can solve the problem using a recursive pattern with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) *(using it and the csv module is a good idea)* or building a state machine.